# Upload de arquivos e outros dados de app Angular 7 para Asp Core Web Api 2.1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, angular-7, asp.net-core-web-api

Estou com um problema no upload de arquivos usando Angular 7 para API escrita em c# Asp Core 2.1. Procurando na web achei vários de exemplos upload do arquivo apenas, porém preciso fazer o upload de arquivo e no mesmo request passar outros dados preenchidos pelo usuário.
Criei uma model afim de receber esses dados digitados pelo usuário:

```
public class MinhaViewModel{

   public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

   public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

E a action que deverá receber os dados digitado e o arquivo ficou assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Publicar")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostDocumentoUsuario([FromForm] MinhaViewModel viewModel, IFormFile file){
    //save file to path and viewModel to database
}
```

Já no Angular escrevi o seguinte código:

```
publicaArquivoUsuario(dadosUsuario):Observable<any>{
   var data  = new FormData();
   data.append('usuarioId', dadosUsuario.usuarioId);
   data.append('descricao', dadosUsuario.descricao);
   data.append('file', dadosUsuario.file); //dadosUsuario.file é do tipo File

   return this.http.post("urlApi", data, httpOptions);
}
```

Usando a interface do `Swagger` o request funciona bem, mas fazendo o request pelo Angular sempre tenho como retorno `Erro 500`, sendo que a action não é chamada. Já especifiquei no cabeçalho da requisição `'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'`.

Answer (score -1):

Eu uso o ng2-file-upload (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload), porém acredito que você precise colocar tudo no mesmo model, veja meu exemplo:

Enviado o arquivo e os dados adicionais (usando o ng2-file-upload, porém é mesma coisa do seu código):

```
  this.uploader.onBuildItemForm = (fileItem: any, form: any)=>{
        form.append('teste1', 'texto teste 1');
        form.append('teste2', 'texto teste 2');
        return {fileItem, form};
    }
```

Front-End:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebendo no backend:

```
    [Route("TesteUpload")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TesteUpload([FromForm]Modal modal)
    {
        SendPreProposalCommand cmd = new SendPreProposalCommand(modal.file.FileName, Path.GetExtension(modal.file.FileName), modal.file);
        return await _mediator.Send(cmd) ? (IActionResult)Ok() : BadRequest();

    }

    public class Modal {
        public string Teste1 { get; set; }
        public string Teste2 { get; set; }
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    }
```

Watch:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso basta mudar o back-end para:

Model:

```
public class MinhaViewModel{

   public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

   public string Descricao { get; set; }

   public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Publicar")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostDocumentoUsuario([FromForm] MinhaViewModel viewModel){
    //save file to path and viewModel to database
}
```

Comment: Este trecho de código `this.uploader.onBuildItemForm`... ficou em que parte do código? No construtor da component?

Comment: Isso é o plugin (ng2-file-uploader) do angular para enviar no post do arquivo. Seria o seu publicaArquivoUsuario, no seu caso só precisa adicionar o IFormFile como uma propriedade dentro da sua "MInhaViewModel"  que acredito que já resolva.

Comment: Editei a resposta, vê se ajuda. :)